# Element won't take up remaining height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get `main` and `div#undermain` to take up the remaining height of the layout, but they won't do it. Here's the HTML (using Tailwind utility classes):

```
<body>
  <div class="min-h-screen w-screen overflow-auto bg-black">
    <nav
      class="flex w-full items-center justify-start gap-3 border-b-2 border-b-gray-800 py-3 pr-6 pl-3"
    >
      <img src="./someurl.svg" />
      <h1 class="text-2xl text-green-500">Delivert</h1>
    </nav>
    <main class="h-full w-full">
      <div id="undermain" class="flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center">
        <button class="bg-green-500">
          sign in
        </button>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm aware that flexbox is an easy approach to such a problem, but the only thing I've tried that worked was the following:

1. give the highest `div` (the one right under `body`) `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`
2. give `main` `flex-grow: 1` and `display: flex`
3. remove `height: 100%` from `#undermain`

But I feel like this solution is weird and not CSS-y.

[Here's a sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-butterfly-v48zj7?file=/index.html:395-2617)

Comment: why do you think using flexbox for this is weird and not CSS-y? people used to use `position: absolute` to solve this, and that's even less *CSS-y* imo

Comment: It's not weird if it works :)

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned in your question, you have achieved your requirement by using `flexbox`. If you are still looking for alternate solution, you can use `table` and `table-rows` tbh I would personally go with `flexbox`, I think my solution is not more css-y than `flexbox`.

Here is the example using `table`:

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body>
  <div class="table min-h-screen w-screen overflow-auto bg-black">
    <nav class="flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-start gap-3 border-b-2 border-b-gray-800 py-3 pl-3 pr-6">
      <img src="./someurl.svg" />
      <h1 class="text-2xl text-green-500">Delivert</h1>
    </nav>
    <main class="relative table-row h-full w-full">
      <div id="undermain" class="table-cell h-full w-full">
        <button class="bg-green-500">sign in</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `<nav>` has a height of 58px including the padding and border, so you can use `calc` and minimum-height on `div#undermain`. The key value here is `min-h-[calc(100vh-58px)]`.

```
<div class="min-h-screen w-screen overflow-auto bg-black">
  <nav class="flex w-full items-center justify-start gap-3 border-b-2 border-b-gray-800 py-3 pl-3 pr-6">
    <img src="./someurl.svg" />
    <h1 class="text-2xl text-green-500">Delivert</h1>
  </nav>
  <main class="w-full">
    <div id="undermain" class="flex min-h-[calc(100vh-58px)] w-full items-center justify-center">
      <button class="bg-green-500">sign in</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/KEIQnQSERc

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you a basic example. Push away from the parent `flex` element.
P.S. I advise you to try to understand how simple css works before using tailwindcss. With best regards ✌️.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main,
main > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Delivert</h1>
</nav>
<main>
  <div>
    <button>sign in</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Actually this isn't very different from the solution I propose in the question, except maybe for `flex: auto`, which is redundant anyway as it subsumes three other declarations only one of which is needed (flex-grow: 1). Also, I don't get the whole "learn CSS first" argument. The difference with Tailwind is crisper syntax, otherwise each utility class is equal to exactly one CSS rule, so it's not less "simple" than plain CSS.

Comment: Friend, maybe I misunderstood your question a little, but I gave you the right answer. Thanks for the minus)) If this behavior of flexbox seems strange to you, then it doesn't to me. I give advice on learning css, because I see your code (for example, the `w-full` class where it is not needed). In no way did I want to offend you.

Comment: I'm not offended and I'm not the person who downvoted you. I'm just saying, if I made a silly CSS mistake, I would have made it in plain CSS just as well. E.g. if I were using plain CSS, I'd needlessly put `width: 100%` where it's not necessary. Using Tailwind doesn't exacerbate things.